# How to replace all href elements when mouseovers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to replace all `href="javascript:void(0)"` to `href="http://google.com"` when **mouseover** the image *caladd.gif* with Javascript and jQuery.

**Summary:** That means whenever the mouse is over the image, it will **trigger** the Javascript or jQuery to change the href to another link.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView">
<div class="ms-acal-header">
<div>
    <table class="ms-acal-month">
    </table>
    <div class="ms-acal-vlink">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add" evtid="new_item">
                        <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/caladd.gif">Add</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"][evtid="new_item"]').hover(
          function () {
              $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
          }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/nALMw/

Comment: It works for me too.  Do you possibly have a plugin that conflicts JS or iframe behavior?

Comment: **@skzryzg, **@Anton**: This doesn't work in my SharePoint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the specified approach that Calendar view is not yet generated when an event handler is bound to the `mouseover` JavaScript event.

It is recommended to take a look at a different approach, where instead of modifying DOM of Calendar, you could customize the Calendar control behavior and properties.

### How to customize Calendar New Item link

Rendering template for `New Item` link is defined in `sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js`:

```
<a evtid=\"new_item\" title=\"{1}\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\"/><span class=\"ms-addcolumn-span\"><img class=\"ms-addcolumn-icon\" border=\"0\" src=\"{2}\"/></span>{0}</a>
```

Rendering template could be overridden and the following code sample demonstrates how to set Calendar `New Item` `href` attribute to `https://www.google.com/calendar/render`

```
function setNewItemUrl(url)
{
   //get New Item template      
   var newItemTemplate = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarVirtualItem.prototype.$7l_0;
   //override template
   SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarVirtualItem.prototype.$7l_0 = newItemTemplate.replace('javascript:void(0)',url);
}

function registerAddItemLink() 
{           
   setNewItemUrl('https://www.google.com/calendar/render');
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerAddItemLink,"SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
```

Usage:

- Add CEWP on Calendar page
- Insert the specified JavaScript code into `Content` property

> Note: Have been tested in SharePoint 2013